# JS nearest li to the scroll position

Tags: javascript, scroll, scroll-position

I have got a list (#js-list-scroll) in my page, some items (li) in the list have a class 'itemPage', what I want to achieve is when the user scroll, I want to find the nearest 'itemPage' to the scroll position.
Something like this:

```
$(window).scrollTop().closest('.itemPage');
```

Youssef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop over all of the lis and compare the position to the current scroll position. Something like:

```
var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
$('li.itemPage').each(function() {
  var top = $(this).position().top;
  if (top > scrollTop) {
    // This is the first li which is visible - do something with it

    return false; // Stop the .each loop from continuing
  }
});
```